# MERN application deployed separately, refresh of browser URL reloads the base route not the refreshed route

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, heroku

I have a MERN app (Mongo, Express, React Node).

The React app is deployed on Firebase where as the Node, Express back-end is deployed on Heroku

In React when refreshing it re-directs to the base URL. You can navigate fine to the pages as needed but refreshing a page just loads the base URL again

https://bosctechlabs.com/fix-react-router-url-doesnt-work-when-refreshing/
[React-router URLs don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

I tried to fix this by adding a catch all to the server.js file as per React docs

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing

However on refresh of a url such as "example.com/123" it just redirects to "example.com"

My server.js catch all is

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
 });
```

I also tried

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile('index.html');
 });
```

I can't seem to find an explanation that covers apps deployed separately and how I can support the refresh of a URL so it's served correctly rather than having to navigate back to it

Adding routes from app.js file

```
if (token){
    routes = (
    
      <Switch>
         <Route path="/" exact>
           <WebsitesDash />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/website/articles/:placeId">
          <WebsiteContent />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/website/:placeId">
          <Website />
        </Route>
        
          <Route path="/home" exact>
            <Websites />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/dashboard" exact>
            <WebsitesDash />
        </Route>

        <Route path="/newwebsite" exact>
            <NewWebsite />
        </Route>

        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    );
  } else {
    //not logged in routes
    routes = (
      <Switch>
      <Route path="/users" exact>
        <Users />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/login" exact>
        <BasicAuth />
      </Route>
      <Redirect to="/login" />
    </Switch>
    );
  }

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ 
          isLoggedIn: !!token,
          token: token,
          userId: userId,
           login: login, logout: logout}}>
  <Router>
    <MainNavigation />
    <Container>
    <main>
    {routes}
   
    </main>
    </Container>
  </Router>
  </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Is the redirect happening on the server side or client side? Check Chrome Dev Tools Network tab to see if the React app is delivered when visiting `example.com/123`.

Comment: In the network tab on reload I can see it loading the chunks.js but that looks after the re-direct maybe?

Comment: Can you show your React routing code? Do you use any `<Redirect />`?

Comment: Added routes code in

Comment: I imagine `<Redirect to="/" />` is the issue. Is that necessary? What happens if you remove it?